# difference between using Vue Router replace and route redirect in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I do not know the difference between  using   Router replace and route redirect
and  how to use them in my project I am new in vue.js

Answer (score 1):

The [Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/) should give you all information necessary.
But to answer your question:
[router.replace()](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#replace-1) replaces the current entry in the history stack, while [route.redirect()](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#redirect-1) actually redirects to another path, having both in the history stack.

a redirect will be triggered before any navigation guard and trigger a new navigation to the desired path.